# Adding a simple row into a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I was spending hours trying to do such a simple thing,
I have a dataframe:

```
  a b c d
0 1 2 3 4
1 5 6 7 8
2 2 3 4 5
3 5 6 7 8
4 1 2 3 4
```

I have a dictionary:

```
dic = {'b':6,'d':2}
```

I would like to do 2 different things :

1. Simply add a row to the df, with this `dic` using NaN for column 'a' and 'c'
2. Modify a row with a condition `a=3`, with this dictionary. For this I tried :

`df.loc[df['date'] == date, dic.keys()] =  dic.values()`

Which provide strange results, like values inside a `()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For new row with default `RangeIndex` use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
dic = {'b':6,'d':2}
df.loc[len(df)] = dic
```

For modify columns by condition working well for me with your solution, for oldier pandas/python version convert `keys` and `values` to lists:

```
dic = {'b':60,'d':20}

df.loc[df['a'] == 1, list(dic.keys())] = list(dic.values())
print (df)
     a   b    c   d
0  1.0  60  3.0  20
1  5.0   6  7.0   8
2  2.0   3  4.0   5
3  5.0   6  7.0   8
4  1.0  60  3.0  20
5  NaN   6  NaN   2
```

EDIT:

```
dic = {'b':60,'d':20}
val = 10

m = df['a'] == val
if m.any():
    df.loc[m, list(dic.keys())] = list(dic.values())
else:
    df.loc[len(df)] = {**dic, **{'a':val}}
print (df)

    a   b    c   d
0   1   2  3.0   4
1   5   6  7.0   8
2   2   3  4.0   5
3   5   6  7.0   8
4   1   2  3.0   4
5  10  60  NaN  20
```

Comment: thanks again! the second adds values with a () in them..

Comment: @gotiredofcoding - Second working for me correct, can you show your wrong ouput?

Comment: thanks, i will check again and post, will accept anyway!

Comment: ok turns out we need to do list(dic.keys()) and same for values...

Comment: just to add something small please, what if the loc with condition can't find that column value - how could i make it so that it will add a row automatically if it couldn't find the specific row in the condition df.loc[df['a'] == 1 ..?

Comment: @gotiredofcoding - If `df['a'] == 10` add new row with `a=10, b=60, c=NaN, d=20` ?

Comment: @gotiredofcoding - Add to EDIT, what I means.

Comment: thanks man! (also the code you put in your profile to contact you is genius :) )